# Recorrer un arreglo JSON y mostrar ciertos datos PHP

Tags: mysql, json, php7

Un `JSON` me esta respondiendo lo siguiente:

```
[
 {
 emple_cedula: "7913",
 emple_nombre: "PEPITO",
 emple_apellido: "PEREZ",
 resultado: "60"
 },
 {
 emple_cedula: "7913",
 emple_nombre: "PEPITO",
 emple_apellido: "PEREZ",
 resultado: "50"
 },
 {
 emple_cedula: "987654",
 emple_nombre: "VANESSA",
 emple_apellido: "PAZ",
 resultado: "100"
 },
 {
 emple_cedula: "987654",
 emple_nombre: "VANESSA",
 emple_apellido: "PAZ",
 resultado: "73"
 },
]
```

¿Como podría hacer que `php` me muestre un solo nombre con todos los resultados asignados a este?.

**Ejemplo:**

```
7913 PEPITO PEREZ 60 50 <-(Estos son los resultados)
987654 VANESSA PAZ 100 73 <-(Estos son los resultados)
```

**CODIGO PHP**

```
if($response)
{   
    $personal = array();            
    foreach ($response as $respuesta)
    {
        if (!in_array(array($respuesta->emple_cedula, $respuesta->emple_nombre,$respuesta->emple_apellido), $personal)) {
            $personal[] = array($respuesta->emple_cedula, $respuesta->emple_nombre,$respuesta->emple_apellido,);                    
        }               
    }

    $datos['personal'] = $personal;
    echo json_encode($datos);
}
```

Con este codigo al ver que me imprimir echo json_encode($datos) me arroja esto:

```
 7913 PEPITO PEREZ 
    987654 VANESSA PAZ
```

> ¿Pero entonces que debo hacer en mi codigo php para que me imprima

```
7913 PEPITO PEREZ 60 50 
    987654 VANESSA PAZ 100 73
```

?

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: Quieres ahora sacar lo que guardaste en `$datos`? y esto mediante mismo php?

Comment: No entendi muy bien la pregunta, pero lo que necesito es que al ver lo que me arroja $datos me muestre el nombre de los usuarios pero con los resultados y no me los duplique sino que tome un solo registro pero que si me muestre todos los resultados que el tiene asignado.....ya que si yo en el array pongo $respuesta->resultado solamente me va amostrar un solo resultado EJEMPLO: 7913 PEPITO PEREZ 60,,,,,
987654 VANESSA PAZ 100

Comment: Y yo me pregunto: **¿por qué el JSON te está enviando los datos duplicados?**, ¿acaso no es el JSON lo que debes corregir para que **no** duplique los datos? ¿O sea que si hay un millón de registros el JSON manda dos millones porque a él le da la gana? Pues noooo, controla ese JSON, resuelve el problema en el origen, no en el destino.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por tu comentario pero al parecer has dedico tu tiempo a una respuesta poco constructiva, los datos no se estan duplicando, ya que si estuviera duplicando los resultados serian iguales, cabe decir que el usuario puede tener un millon de registros pero el resultado siempre va a cambiar.

Comment: Amigo tienes a PEPITO PEREZ 2 veces, y a VANESSA PAZ 2 veces. Eso se llama **redundancia de datos**. Puedes hacer que tu JSON te devuelva **los datos que se repiten una sola vez** y en un arreglo, array, matriz o como quieras llamarle los datos que varían,  que este caso son sólo los datos correspondientes a **resultado**. Si a esto le llamas una **respuesta poco constructiva** que le vamos a hacer. La **redundancia de datos** es una mala práctica de programación, afecta al rendimiento de las aplicaciones y luego hay que inventar rompecabezas para presentar los datos. **Ese** es el problema.

Comment: amigo has visto que PEPITO PEREZ Y VANESSA PAZ tienen resultados diferentes? donde esta la redundancia?

Comment: Un JSON **optimizado** sería: `[{
 emple_cedula: "7913",
 emple_nombre: "PEPITO",
 emple_apellido: "PEREZ",
 resultado: ["60","50"]
 },{
 emple_cedula: "987654",
 emple_nombre: "VANESSA",
 emple_apellido: "PAZ",
 resultado: ["100","73"]
 }]` luego lees `resultado` dentro de un bucle y listo. A eso me refiero.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57416/discussion-between-jdavid-and-a-cedano).

Comment: La redundancia es que tienes **dos objetos JSON con casi los mismos datos** y si es un millón pasaría lo mismo. Como te mostré en el ejemplo, un JSON optimizado debería tener **un solo objeto por cada persona y dentro de `resultado` una matriz con todos los datos que varían**. Así, si PEPITO tiene 1 millón de resultados **no tienes por qué repetir 1 millón de veces su nombre y sus datos**, es **el mismo PEPITO**, entonces: `{ emple_cedula: "7913", emple_nombre: "PEPITO", emple_apellido: "PEREZ", resultado: ["60","50","1","3",..... y hasta un millón, o dos millones  o todo lo que quieras] } `

Comment: Disculpa. Después leer la acotación de @A.Cedano que no siempre es aplicable. Me pregunto.. estos datos que vienen en el json, puedes modificar la fuente? o vienen desde un sistema externo al tuyo? o sea .. cual es el motivo de la transformación? si puedes modificar la fuente, te evitarías hacer todo el ciclo ese que tienes.

Comment: Hola @ArieCwHat yo estoy haciendo una peticion y la base de datos me responde esa manera, sino que al hablar de json es porque es una de las formas que uso para imprimir, es como si yo usara un print_r($datos),var_dump($datos),etc sino que yo uso echo json_encode($datos) por que luego lo voy a enviar a un js pero a mi lo que me importa es desintregar eso que esta recibiendo el json dentro de php con el foreach para luego "darselo molidito" a JS.

Comment: puedes agregar tus comentarios importantes a la pregunta? pueden aclarar muchas cosas, como que la estructura del json es una consulta a la BD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta a la base de datos parece ser del tipo Join. Puedes modificar tu consulta a la base de datos? creo que es mejor procesar los datos desde mysql que usar php (que es mas lento y necesitas generar un mapa) para recorrer todos los valores.

```
SELECT  p.emple_cedula, p.emple_nombre, p.emple_apellido, GROUP_CONCAT(v.resultado) as resultados
FROM    persona p
JOIN    valores v
ON      v.emple_cedula = p.emple_cedula
GROUP BY
        p.emple_cedula
```

Mira [la respuesta completa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132359/6658955)

La idea principal de cambiar la consulta es que te devuelva desde la consulta JOIN común que queda:

```
cédula    nombre       apellido      valor
7913      PEPITO       PEREZ         60
7913      PEPITO       PEREZ         50 
987654    VANESSA      PAZ           100
987654    VANESSA      PAZ           73
```

A la forma en la que los valores por cada persona están separados por coma de una forma similar a esta:

```
cédula    nombre       apellido      valores
7913      PEPITO       PEREZ         60, 50 
987654    VANESSA      PAZ           100, 73
```

Después si quieres aun así el array usas `explode(',', $myString)` para convertirlo desde el valor por comas a un array, o puedes enviarlo así y que el cliente lo procese.

Si no quieres modificar tu consulta o no se adapta el comentario. Debes usar un array dentro  del foreach. Tu array guarda el `emple_cedula` como indice del arreglo que mantiene los datos ordenados (esto es un ejemplo):

```
$personal = array();            
foreach ($response as $respuesta)
{
    if(!isset($personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]){
        $personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]['emple_cedula'] = $respuesta->emple_cedula;
        $personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]['emple_nombre'] = $respuesta->emple_nombre;
        $personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]['emple_apellido'] = $respuesta->emple_apellido;
        $personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]['resultado'] = array();
    }

    $personal[$respuesta->emple_cedula]['resultado'][] = $respuesta->resultado;
}

$datos['personal'] = $personal;
echo json_encode($datos);
```

Esta es la idea, puede tener errores, pero básicamente usas el id de usuario como clave para indexar los resultados. Esto es mejor que usar `in_array` que es una búsqueda secuencial.

Comment: men excelente..te agradezco un montón es exactamente lo que requería.

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta. Así es como tenían que estructurarse los datos. Como te dije en comentarios anteriores, @JDavid, el problema estaba en el origen, no en el destino. Saludos.